# bash can you write a script file that modifies itself for the next time it is called?

Tags: bash, counter, self-modifying

Let's say as an example that I wanted to write a script file that not only kept count of how many times it's been called, but would average the time that it has been called since the first time.  and to do this without relying on environmental variables or secondary files.  And report the number of lapsed days as well.  This would mean that it would have to be self-modifying.  Now when a script is loaded and executed, the saved version on disk can be changed without effecting the copy in memory, so that works, or should.  Just change the copy on file.

But making it happen can be a bit tricky.  So what is your best solution?

Comment: Why do this? Why not use a secondary file? This script would not be a very good UNIX citizen. For instance, my systems have a read-only filesystem where only `/var` and `/tmp` are writable. Scripts, which are mostly stored in `/bin` and `/usr/bin`, can't be readily modified.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a bit weird, but a bash script is just text, so you can always edit it IF you have permission:

Take this example:

```
#!/bin/bash
VAR=1
let VAR=VAR+1
echo Set to $VAR
perl -pi -e 's/^VAR=\d+/VAR='$VAR'/' $0
```

Trying it out:

```
$ /tmp/foo.sh
Set to 9
$ /tmp/foo.sh
Set to 10
$ /tmp/foo.sh
Set to 11
```